# Why am I not able to check for two parameters in post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, rest

I am making a post request and I want to check if any parameter is not left empty. It is being checked for one parameter but not for both.

```
app.post("/tshirt/:id", (req, res) => {
    const {id} = req.params;    
    const {logo, size} = req.body;

    if(logo === undefined) {
        res.status(418).send("It needs a logo");
    }

    if(size === undefined) {
        res.status(418).send("It needs a size");
    }

    else {
        res.status(200).send({
            tshirt: ` with your ${logo} is ready`,
            size: `${size}`
        });
    }
})
```

When no size is passed
[image]
When no logo is passed
[image]

When both parameters are passed
[image]
I want to get the result only when both the parameters are satisfied.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [app.get - is there any difference between res.send vs return res.send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055600/app-get-is-there-any-difference-between-res-send-vs-return-res-send)

Comment: The `else` only pertains to the last `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would return an "error" response if either one or both properties aren't set, with an appropriate message for each case

So, in the code below, the "error" message can either be

- It needs a logo
- It needs a size
- It needs a logo and a size

.
app.post("/tshirt/:id", (req, res) => {
const {id} = req.params;
const {logo, size} = req.body;

```
    if (logo === undefined || size === undefined) {
        const msg=[];

        if (logo === undefined) {
            msg.push("logo");
        }

        if (size === undefined) {
            msg.push("size");
        }
        // use return here so no `else` is required
        return res.status(418).send(`It needs a ${msg.join(" and a ")}`);
    }
    res.status(200).send({
        tshirt: ` with your ${logo} is ready`,
        size: `${size}`
    });
});
```

Though, to reduce the nesting of `if`, I'd probably do it like this (though, many people prefer to handle error cases first)

```
app.post("/tshirt/:id", (req, res) => {
    const {id} = req.params;    
    const {logo, size} = req.body;

    if (logo !== undefined && size !== undefined) {
        // return here so no `else` is required
        return res.status(200).send({
            tshirt: ` with your ${logo} is ready`,
            size: `${size}`
        });
    }
    const msg=[];

    if (logo === undefined) {
        msg.push("logo");
    }

    if (size === undefined) {
        msg.push("size");
    }
    res.status(418).send(`It needs a ${msg.join(" and a ")}`);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

pay attention to use return in sending response.

```js
app.post("/tshirt/:id", (req, res) => {
    const {id} = req.params;    
    const {logo, size} = req.body;

    if(logo === undefined) {
        return res.status(418).send("It needs a logo");
    } 
    
    if(size === undefined) {
        return res.status(418).send("It needs a size");
    } 
    
     return res.status(200).send({
        tshirt: ` with your ${logo} is ready`,
        size: `${size}`
     });
})
```